# How do I install drivers for TP-Link 802.11ac Wi-Fi USB adapter?

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter, realtek-wireless

New to ubuntu, just need some help conecting wirelessly.

lsusb:

```
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 2357:0101
```

Comment: Is it a USB adapter?

Comment: yes, it is usb 3.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command when the adapter is inserted.

Comment: lsusb returns:Bus 008 Device 003: ID 2357:0101

Comment: And nothing else?

Comment: yes but this was the wireless adapter. It went missing when i removed the usb.

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: All fine up until the last line.

sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0 does not exist.

Comment: Fixed the last command. Just run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the driver this way. Connect to Internet some other way and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
sed -i 's/\#MODULE_VERSION\#/0.1/' rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/dkms.conf
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 0.1
```

Then insert your dongle.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Comment: I'm moving from centos to ubuntu on my desktop because wireless just doesn't work right under centos it seems. (Among other reasons). I want a simple dongle to allow connection to a camera to sync pictures. Ethernet is fine otherwise. Thanks for this. It worked the first time.

Comment: I tried the above steps but I still cannot get the tplink USB net-device to work. I also tried a restart but didn't work either. I can see it listed in `lsusb` but not in `sudo lshw -C network`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Pilot6, thank you very much for providing this.

I ran into some challenges while installing the repository. If you experience similar issues, please feel free try the following solution that worked for me (note, this has enabled to install the drivers and I have not tested the functionality yet):

```
cd /usr/src
sudo cp -r rtl8812au-#MODULE_VERSION# 8812au-1.0
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 1.0
```

Comment: This is not a full answer. Now it looks like a comment. Can you reprpduce the full steps you did? And what is wrong with my commands? They are doing actually the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. They changed the version.

Comment: I fixed it in my answer by another way. Yours is good too.

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions have been tested and do not seem to work. Try the following (update your network interfaces):

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Remove the standard configurations. Check using dmesg which interface is being used (eth0, eth1, etc.) and add the settings for this interface;

```
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 dhcp inet
auto eth1
iface eth1 dhcp inet
```

My issue had to do with the TP Link UE300 usb to ethernet 3.0 adapter which was recognized by ubuntu linux but it did not function. After installing the updates as suggested by @Pilot6 and updating the network interfaces, the adapter started functioning.